# ¿Por que al acceder a elemento de un array muestra undefined?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo el siguiente array:

```
var arrayElementos = ["elemento 1" , "elemento 2" , "elemento 3"];
```

Aplicamos la propiedad `length`:

```
var arrayLargo = arrayElementos.length;
```

Y al hacer `alert(arrayLargo);` devuelve 3.

Trato de acceder al tercer elemento y sale:

```
alert (arrayLargo[3]);
undefined
```

> ¿Porque si hay 3 elementos no puedo acceder a este tercero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto sucede porque en programación los indices de los *arreglos* se empiezan a contar siempre desde **0** y no desde **1**, es decir:

```js
//Número de elementos:     1               2              3    
var arrayElementos = ["elemento 1" , "elemento 2" , "elemento 3"];
//Posición y/o indice:     0               1              2

console.log(arrayElementos[2])
```

Obviamente tu arreglo tiene **3** *elementos*, pero sus *indices* van desde el número **0**

Siempre puedes acceder al último *elemento* de un *arreglo* mediante:

```js
//Número de elementos:     1               2              3    
var arrayElementos = ["elemento 1", "elemento 2", "elemento 3"];
//Posición y/o indice:     0               1              2

var length = arrayElementos.length; // 3

//                                    3    - 1 = 2
var ultimoElemento = arrayElementos[length - 1];

console.log(ultimoElemento);
```